# Catalyst State Restoration via SceneDelegate not working

Tags: ios, uikit, mac-catalyst

When quitting my catalyst application via the dock icon (right click -> quit) my SceneDelegate's `stateRestorationActivity(for scene: UIScene)` method is called and I return a non-nil NSUserActivity.

However, when restarting my application there is no user activity in the `connectionOptions` of `scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions)`

Does this function correctly for anyone else? Do I need to build my UserActivity in a specific way for this to work in Catalyst? It functions correctly when running on iOS.

Comment: State restoration works intermittently for me, but for the most part it’s been broken on Catalyst since day 1. I filed FB6528562 about the issue 11 months ago.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spoke with an engineer during a WWDC2020 Lab about this. My issue, as odd as it seems, was restarting the application too soon after quitting it.

iOS applications running on Catalyst will linger after being quit. This can be observed in Activity Monitor. It was explained that this is the period where the app can finish any registered background tasks.

After waiting for my application to disappear from ActivityMonitor and then relaunching, it restored the activity provided in `stateRestorationActivity(for scene: UIScene)`

Comment: In case this helps anyone else: I also spoke with some Apple engineers during WWDC2020 about related issues. One issue I asked was that application(_:didDiscardSceneSessions:) was not seeming to get called. iPadOS was keeping them around too long after I kill/swiped them in App Switcher, even after waiting seemingly forever. They had me click the power/screen button to put the device to sleep and this caused the sessions to be immediately discarded. So it's interesting that this does happen "eventually" but I'd like more predictable/control.

Answer (score 6):

For reference, there is another possibility: make sure that the System Preference "Close windows when quitting an app" (in the "General" pane - before MacOS 13/Ventura, and in the "Desktop & Dock" -> "Windows & Apps" from Ventura) is unchecked. If checked, state restoration will be disabled when quitting/restarting the app.

Comment: I was wondering why state restoration via `@SceneStorage` did not work in my SwiftUI-based macOS app. Turning off this system setting was the solution.

In macOS 13 (Ventura), the setting is located in "Desktop & Dock" -> "Windows & Apps"

Comment: @KaiOezer Thanks for the update, I updated the answer to include your addition.